# jQuery find element inside h tag. Which DOM selector to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an icon within an h tag:

```
<h4 class="ipro_toggle"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-rotate-270 pull-left toggle_icon"></i>Click Me</h4>
```

I am trying to toggle the class `fa-rotate-270` when the h4 is clicked. There will be multiple elements such as this on one page.

```
    $("h4.ipro_toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle_icon").toggleClass("fa-rotate-270 norotate");
});
```

This is not finding the icon. What DOM selector should I use?

Comment: Thanks for the clear answers. I don't understand the down votes, though. I was clear in what I was asking and I provided code examples.

Comment: Agreed. +1 to compensate

Comment: I'm curious, why did you think `next` would work? Did you read the documentation beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), not `.next()`:

```
$("h4.ipro_toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".toggle_icon").toggleClass("fa-rotate-270 norotate");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways:

```
$(this).children('.toggle_icon').toggleClass('fa-rotate-270 norotate');
```

OR

```
$(this).find('.toggle_icon').toggleClass('fa-rotate-270 norotate');
```

OR

```
$('.toggle_icon', this).toggleClass('fa-rotate-270 norotate');
```

The method you have used (`next`) is invalid here as `.toggle_icon` is not the *next* sibling of the clicked `<h4>` element, but its descendant.

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace next by [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/). In order to get the descendants of your H tag.

```
$(this).find(".toggle_icon").toggleClass("fa-rotate-270 norotate");
```